# How to extend abstract generic abstract interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract

Right now, I am trying to implement an imported Java abstract interface. It is a short interface as follows:

```
public interface USet<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
```

I am trying to use this interface USet with an integer. In my own class, I am trying to extend this class (as I can't invoke it as it is abstract) as so:

```
public class Bag extends USet<Integer>{
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
```

Basically, I really need to use the functions within USet either with a call (which I don't think I can do with abstract interface) or extension. However, I am getting errors when I try to extend it with an Integer into the generic. Is this a scriptic error?

Comment: It should be `public class Bag implements USet<Integer>`, as `USet` is an interface. Furthermore you need to replace all occurences of `T` with `Integer`.

Comment: Please include the concrete compilation error messages.

Comment: It seems you don't really understand interfaces, and the difference between using and extending. Learn these basics first. Generics will come later. Java has a standard Set interface, and several concrete implementations, so this USet interface doesn't make much sense (unless you have a homework asking you to implement a Set, but then you should really explain what you're supposed to do).

Comment: Simply put, `USet` should NOT extend `Iterable`, it should be its own separate interface.  A class that currently implements `USet<T>` should instead implement both `USet<T>` _and_ `Iterable<T>`.  You should extend an interface in only extremely rare circumstances where the sub-interface really is conceptually an extension of the superinterface.  In your example it is not.

Comment: @JimGarrison I disagree. It's very much expected for a set to be iterable: you ant to be able to act on all the elements it contains. BTW, java.util.Set does extend Iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement an interface, and the type in the class will be the Integer in this case, and not a generic one.

You also must add an body when implementing the interface.

Your Bag class should look like this:

```
public class Bag implements USet<Integer> {

@Override
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean add(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Integer remove(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Integer find(Integer x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

**Update**: As [stav-saad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4293203/stav-saad) mentioned the interface is only correctly implemented after implementing (create the method and body) each method of the interface.

Comment: I would add that you also need to actually implement each method's body so that it will actually work